# Im having problems finding the value of the following series and it seems that it needs to be integrated or differentiated and compared to Geo series

Tags: real-analysis

The series is $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}$$(k-1)k(\frac{1}3)^{k+1}$. I´ve looked at Wolfram Alpha and have seen that its equal to 0.25.
My idea is to compare the second derivative of the geometric series which can be written as $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}=$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}$$(k-1)kx^{k-2}$=$\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}$ to it.
For $|x|<1$, specifically $x=\frac{1}3$. There is obviously a strong similarity between these two series and I was hoping to find an answer to how to solve such a problem here in this community. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice first that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k-1)kx^{k-2} = \sum_{k=2}^\infty (k-1)kx^{k-2}.
$$
Moreover,
$$
\sum_{k=2}^\infty (k-1)kx^{k+1} = \sum_{k=2}^\infty (k-1)k\left(x^3x^{k-2}\right) = x^3\sum_{k=2}^\infty (k-1)kx^{k-2}.
$$
Replacing $x$ by $1/3$ on the right and side we obtain
$$
\frac{1}{3^3}\frac{2}{(1-1/3)^{3}} = \frac{2}{3^3}\frac{3^3}{2^3} = \frac{1}{4}
$$

Comment: In the first row, are these two sums really the same or is there maybe a typo? Essentially we have two less summations then if those are the same. Maybe im just confused right now

Comment: @MarcelP Take a look at what the first two terms in the summation evaluate to. That is, what happens when you replace $k$ by $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Think about what happens when you differentiate the individual terms of a power series. What is the derivative of a constant function?

Comment: Oh yes you’re right! Thanks a lot now I get it :) you really helped me!

Comment: You're welcome! You can accept my answer if you wish.